# Xcode - Install additional required components using command line

Tags: xcode, macos

I recently got a used Mac with Mountain Lion on it. I don't know of the admin password or anything, but I do know how to run a command line.

So here's what I am stuck on:
[image: asdf]

When I click install, it asks me for my username and password (which I don't know).

I want to install this via single-user mode (Cmd+S on Startup), which I accepted the license using it.

Do you guys know how I could achieve this?

Comment: `xcode-select --install`? The man page says it pops up a dialog, but if there is no GUI maybe it'll go headless.

Comment: Regardless, it may be better for you to just reset your password in single-user mode. While booted up, open Terminal and type `whoami`. That's your username; when you boot into single-user mode, type `passwd [username]` and enter your new password.

Comment: Well, the --install flag isn't a flag. Any other commands?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't a flag"?

Comment: I mean it says that it's an unknown command option.

Comment: Apparently you have an old version. It's in the man page and works for me.

Comment: My Xcode version is 5.0.1 (I checked by using `xcodebuild -version`)

Comment: My `xcodebuild -version` says 5.0.1 / build 5A2053. What is your `xcode-select -version`?

Comment: `xcode-select -version`
xcode-select version 2311.

Comment: Mhmm. Mine's 2333. Perhaps it's installed with the command-line tools you can't get. Just reset your password in single-user mode and reboot to install the tools.

Answer (score 73):

At least on Xcode 9.2, you could use:

```
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

to accept the agreement and install additional components.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer, OP should accept this one.

Comment: Work for me, Mojave XCode 10

Comment: Works with Xcode 11 on a headless Mojave VM as well.

Comment: Still works with Xcode 12 beta and a headless Catalina VM.

Comment: This still works for the Xcode 12.1 update... it's insane that this is a bug in the first place in Xcode but this does in fact work. Make sure you hard close Xcode before running it.

Answer (score 21):

Resolved this issue using the below commands, it is on OS El Capitan and Xcode beta 7.2

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild  -license accept
sudo installer -pkg /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDevice.pkg -target /
sudo installer -pkg /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg -target /
```

Change the `Xcode-beta.app` path to your own, and you would need sudo(admin) access. Close your Xcode and open again.

Comment: Thanks for this! For anyone wanting to automate a little further,

```for pkg in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/*.pkg; do sudo installer -pkg "$pkg" -target /; done```

Comment: I still experienced the popup in xcode 7.2.1. Also reported here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/34878

Comment: After upgrading to MacOS Sierra I was not able to run Xcode. I will get in to the same window as shown above. I've tried several ways to install, uninstall, upgrade, etc  and this was the only one that helped me.  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: fyi in that folder for xcode 8.3.2 there is also XcodeSystemResources.pkg.

Answer (score 6):

The commandline way to install required components is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -installComponents
```

Comment: this opens the popup dialog and doesn't do it in a "unassisted" kind of way :(

Comment: with xcode beta, the dialog it opens up shows "missing required components"

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a looooooong time after the original post, but just in case anyone else finds this (as I did) while trying to install Xcode 8.2.1 on El Capitan (10.11.6)…

I had all the same problems listed here – long delay for launch, then asking for additional tools to be installed, only to fail. The command line tools install also failed. I tried the various command line solutions listed, but none worked.

However, upon checking the log I saw that I was getting errors with certificates. On a hunch, I decided to put the system clock back to 20 December 2016 - voila, installs work like magic.

Put the clock back to today (30 October 2019) and still seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing.
I went into recovery mode (CMD+R on startup), then to Terminal. I typed in

```
resetpassword
```

which then brought up a dialog of where I can select the user and set the password.

I then set the root password. Now when I can enter an admin password, I type in "root" and the password I set.

I got Xcode to load finally!

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 5.1.1 have a new argument:

```
> xcode -installComponents
```