# Xcode keeps asking in a loop for authorisation on startup asking "Install additional required components?"

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan

XCode always keeps asking for "install additional required components" in a loop, Has anyone faced this issue.

I am using MaC OX El capitan 10.11.1 and xcode 7.2 beta

[image]

Comment: may be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668537/xcode-install-additional-required-components-using-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Try this from a terminal window:

`git status`

or

`sudo git status`

If it asks you do install additional Xcode components, do so. It may ask you read and agree to an End User License Agreement (which I think you must do to proceed).