# Xcode - Install additional required components

Tags: xcode, macos

We have some Macs that students are logging in to to use Xcode through VNC and using Windows domain accounts.  Every time a new user logs in, an admin has to install the extra required components for them.  We would like this to happen automatically for every user.  We have tried running the commands from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668537/xcode-install-additional-required-components-using-command-line) and [this site](https://github.com/munki/munki/wiki/Xcode), but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

We have seen some sites talking about repackaging it for some reason.. but we don't have access to the developer site that they are pulling the package from.