# Multiple line comment in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode8

I just upgraded to Xcode GM 8.0 and noticed ⌘ + / is not commenting out selected lines. Is there another command to comment out multiple lines in Xcode 8?

Comment: It works for me.  Do you see any conflicts in Preferences -> Key Bindings -> Conflicts?

Comment: I had 8 Command Conflicts none were ⌘ + /. I removed them anyway then restarted and relaunched Xcode. Still the command is not working, just get an error chime when pressed. I do see the Command in KeyBindings window under Comment Selection for the various editors. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: I am encountering this issue too with the public release of Xcode 8. I also have the same 8 conflicts and none of them is the command for line comment like what @DaveLass mentioned

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Xcode7 and earlier versions, the commenting option was available in Editor  > Structure > Comment Selection. In Xcode 8 this option is disabled.

To enable these options run `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` and restart your Mac.

There is thread on [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53339) regarding this issue and several possible fixes. For me running the above command and restarting the Mac did the fix.

Also in [Xcode 8 release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) it states:

> To use the Editor's Comment/Uncomment Selection and Add Documentation commands—as well as other installed Xcode Extensions—on OS X version 10.11, launch Xcode and install additional system components, then restart your Mac. (26106213)

Comment: This worked at first for Xcode 8. But then I ran the 8.1 beta and it's stopped working again for 8! And now it won't work at all, even after re-running xpccachectl and restarting the Mac. What the...? As @jwhat said, this is just ridiculous.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When i do ⌘ + / it still open the Help menu. 

Comment: this does not work for me . when i fire this command system give me error sudo: usr/libexec/xpccachectl: command not found

Comment: Have you installed xCode additional components @HimanshuMoradiya? If not, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23026952/2559325

Comment: @bob You might need to have a look at fr0sky's answer below to solve your problem if you're still having this issue.

Comment: This works for me in Xcode 8.3. The only thing I noticed is when I installed a recent Xcode update, multi-line comments stopped working and I had to run this again

Comment: May 16, 2017 and we're still dealing with this. Thank you for the working answer.

Comment: This is a consistent issue for me and this ALWAYS solves the issue!

Answer (score 6):

I finally figured this one out, drove me crazy…

These are the preconditions for the bug to arise:

1. '/' needs to be accessed with the shift key, like i.e. on German keyboards.
2. There is a global OS X hotkey to access help with shift+cmd+'/', which is the default

Under these preconditions there is not conflict showing in XCode keyboard preferences, but it trying to invoke cmd+'/' triggers the global help hotkey anyway.

How to fix it?

Simply remap or switch off the global hotkey to show help in 
system preferences > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts, select app shortcuts in the list on the left.

Comment: Thanks! Merci! Danke! Gracias!!

Answer (score 5):

Go to Systems Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts and disable Show Help menu option.

That worked for me after try with all possible solutions.

[image]

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. It's probably more related to a macOS update than to a Xcode.

Comment: This solution worked for me after restarting my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens to me (even with Xcode7, and just confirmed still with Xcode8) after opening the documentation window (Help -> Documentation and API Reference or cmd+shift+0). Here are a few things that have fixed it when it was happening to me:

- Restart Xcode (realize you've already tried this, but including it for posterity)
- Close the documentation window
- With only 1 Xcode window open, hit cmd+~ a couple times
- Wish really really hard

Answer (score 1):

If you have a nested /* anywhere, including in a string, it breaks the XCode comment command. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424349/5135551).